# Argument type '[MGLPointAnnotation]' does not conform to expected type 'MGLAnnotation'

Tags: dictionary, annotations, mapbox, unwrap

I have recently started learning swift, and have now taken the next step into making my own map. I have already succesfully made an app with mapkit, and I am now trying my luck with mapbox, as I like its design features.

I have contructed a dictionary, which holds my location data, and afterwards I am making a loop, which adds the data to my map. However I am now stuck, as I get the following error:

" Argument type '[MGLPointAnnotation]' does not conform to expected type 'MGLAnnotation'

This happens when I try to mapView.addAnnotation with my dictionary. I have come so far to learn it has something to do with unwrapping the values in the dictionary, but when I force unwrap by writing mapView.addAnnotation(annotations as! MGLAnnotation), my app crashes.

Can someone show me in the right direction? I'm not looking for a hotfix, but more in finding out where I am getting things wrong. Thanks alot!

Here is the code:

```
let locations = [
        ["name" : "Apple Inc.",
         "latitude" : 37.33187,
         "longitude" : -122.02951,
         "mediaURL" : "http://www.apple.com"],
        ["name" : "BJ's Restaurant & Brewhouse",
         "latitude" : 37.33131,
         "longitude" : -122.03175,
         "mediaURL" : "http://www.bjsrestaurants.com"]
    ]

    var annotations = [MGLPointAnnotation]()

    for dictionary in locations {
        let latitude = CLLocationDegrees(dictionary["latitude"] as! Double)
        let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(dictionary["longitude"] as! Double)
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let name = dictionary["name"] as! String
        let discription = dictionary["mediaURL"] as! String
        let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        annotation.title = "\(name)"
        annotation.subtitle = "\(discription)"
        annotations.append(annotation)
    }

mapView.addAnnotation(annotations as! MGLAnnotation)
```

Comment: I still experience this problem. If anyone has a solution, or just a general direction where I can find more info, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast an array of something to a single object of another... `annotations` is an array, while `MGLAnnotation` is a single object.

So change
`mapView.addAnnotation(annotations as! MGLAnnotation)`
to
`mapView.addAnnotation(annotations as! [MGLAnnotation])`

That should remove your error... However you are also using the method `addAnnotation` which is expecting only 1 object as an argument. So try:
`mapView.addAnnotation(annotations[0])`

Note: My first piece of the solution is just demonstrating the solution to the error - it still wont work because of the "expecting only 1 object" situation.

Hope this helps and explains some things :)